# Constrain type and attribute within a python container

Tags: python, oop, containers

I would like to build a container to store objects and I would like to constraint the container to store only objects of same type (type not defined a priori) and with a different property (e.g. `name` in the example below so that it could be an index).

Here is an example of the expected behavior assuming the container is derived from a `list` object.

```
obj1 = Foo(name='Jon')
obj2 = Foo(name='Doe')
obj3 = Foo(name='Jon')
obj4 = Bar(name='Bob')

>>> MyContainer()
[]
>>> MyContainer([obj1, obj2])
[Foo(name='Jon'), Foo(name='Doe')]
>>> MyContainer([obj1, obj4])
TypeError: mixed types
>>> MyContainer([obj1, obj3])
ValueError: Same 'name' attribute
```

I would like this behavior to remain whatever which method is used for populating the container: `__init__`, `__add__`, `__iadd__`, `append`, ...

However, if possible, I would like that an empty container could hold any type as long as it is all the same.

I wonder what should be the proper way to implement it and I am looking for suggestion. So far, I thought about deriving it from a `list` and rewrite the methods but I don't feel comfortable with this. Should I decorate it? Should I build a container from scratch ? Is there already an existing container to fit my purpose (a kind of dict or a pandas.Dataframe) ?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Maybe ``collections.abc.MutableSequence` could be a good starting point...

Comment: @internet_user I could use such a container to simplify a long piece of code where I use `list` to store object in this way. I have many containers but all contain the same type of objects with attributes that could only be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive your class from `list` to achieve this and then check at all the points where something could enter your instance that whatever enters is a `Foo`:

```
class Foo: pass

class FooList(list):
  def __init__(self, elements):
    assert all(isinstance(element, Foo) for element in elements)
    super().__init__(elements)

  def append(self, element):
    assert isinstance(element, Foo)
    super().append(element)

  def __add__(self, other):
    return FooList(super().__add__(other))  # will do the checks implicitly
```

This will only check at creation time.  You could go ahead now and override all the other points (`__iadd__()`, `__setitem__()`, …) and introduce checks there as well.

My current implementation only checks for the type of the elements.  You could check for more things of course, like the check for the same names you mentioned.

For just the types, I'm not sure this is a good way to go, though.  How about using static typing for Python instead?  That would not introduce so much overhead at runtime.

Comment: Instead of `assert` you could raise a `ValueError()` of course, depending on whether you want that the checks can be optimized away or not via commandline switch (asserts can be switched off).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is somehow what I had in mind but I am not sure this should be the way to go as well. I did not know about static typing and I will check the doc.

Comment: Static typing works sufficiently well but is rather new yet, so not every esoteric aspect is covered completely.  For your case it should work quite well.